# Objective-C to Delphi for +(id)sharedDevice

Tags: objective-c, delphi, delphi-xe5, linea-pro

I'm trying to develop an iPhone app using the Linea Pro 5 SDK and Delphi XE5. I am translating the `lineaSDK.h` file to Delphi and I do not know how to translate this line from the SDK:

```
@interface Linea  : NSObject
...

/**
 Creates and initializes new Linea class instance or returns already initalized one. Use this function, if you want to access the class from different places
 @return shared class instance
 **/

+(id)sharedDevice`  // <--- this is where I am getting stumped.
...
```

I've read the Apple documentation on what (id) is and have Googled for a hint but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know Object Pascal, but it's analogous to this in Java: public static Object sharedDevice();  '+' means it's a class-level method and 'id' is essentially saying "an object" without giving any hint of the type.

Comment: From the comment in the .h file it states that +(id)sharedDevice creates and initialises a new Linea class instance. So really, it is the constructor for the Linea class. (At least that's how I interpret it.)

Comment: Stylistically, class methods named "sharedXXXX" typically refer to a singleton, so it's typically used as an accessor (not as factory, although calling it may create the instance the first time it's called).